# why JPA Diagram Editor does not open?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, dali

i use eclipse kepler and download eclipseLink 2.5.0 and add to libraries.
also download JPA Diagram Editor from Marketplace.

but, when right-click on JPA Content, no items is exist,
and, when right-click on project and from "JPA Tools" menu click on "open diagram", no things is happened.

also, when in project's properties click on JPA Diagram Editor, show error.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you update the plugins via 'Check for Updates' then you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 4):

Install "Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Diagram Editor" from

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

Answer (score 3):

In Neon, the problem is fixed.

I verfied by

- installing eclipse-jee-neon-R-win32-x86_64.zip on a vanilla Windows VM
- adding JPA Diagram Editor 1.2.300.v201604110621 from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon, which pulled in Graphiti 0.13.0.v20160608-1043